# Run-time error -2147467259 (80004005) on VBA macro call

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

I used the code from this website:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26587283/ppRefresh.bas

to create a button in excel spreadsheet that refreshes powerpivot data.
Unfortunately, it threw a run-time error -2147467259 (80004005).
I have 11 tables in my powerpivot data. When I deleted one of them, everything was fine.

Comment: Look, you need to make it easy for folks to help you. Please post your code here, not in a link. Don't post everything; just the relevant bits. Format it properly using the `{}` button. Tell us on what line the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still have this issue. But try increasing the timeout, it could be that it takes longer than 30 seconds to refresh power pivot data.

Change

```
Private Function doXMLA(cnn, databaseID As String, Optional dimensionID As String = "", Optional timeout As Long = 30)
```

To

```
Private Function doXMLA(cnn, databaseID As String, Optional dimensionID As String = "", Optional timeout As Long = 300)
```

For example